# How is page rendered if neither getStaticProps nor getServerSideProps is created in a page?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I have an existing project built with Next.js but none of the two rendering methods are defined in some of the pages.

How are those pages rendered if neither `getStaticProps` nor `getServerSideProps` are present?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a page does not contain any data fetching methods (`getStaticProps`/`getServerSideProps`) then it will use static generation. This means Next.js generates the page HTML at build time, this HTML will then be reused on each request to the page.

From the [Static Generation without data](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering) documentation:

> By default, Next.js pre-renders every page. This means that Next.js generates HTML for each page in advance, instead of having it all done by client-side JavaScript.